# _int64 does not name a type

Tags: iphone, int64, pch

In my **pch** file I have the following definitions:

```
#if (_MSC_VER < 1300)
   typedef signed char       int8_t;
   typedef signed short      int16_t;
   typedef signed int        int32_t;
   typedef unsigned char     uint8_t;
   typedef unsigned short    uint16_t;
   typedef unsigned int      uint32_t;
#else
   typedef signed __int8     int8_t;
   typedef signed __int16    int16_t;
   typedef signed __int32    int32_t;
   typedef unsigned __int8   uint8_t;
   typedef unsigned __int16  uint16_t;
   typedef unsigned __int32  uint32_t;
#endif
typedef signed __int64       int64_t;
typedef unsigned __int64     uint64_t;
```

When I build my application I get an error at

```
typedef signed __int64       int64_t;
typedef unsigned __int64     uint64_t;
```

which says that  **_int64 does not name a type**. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this include

```
#include <inttypes.h>
```

Then use uint64_t or int64_t.

see below

```
#include <inttypes.h>


#if (_MSC_VER < 1300)
   typedef signed char       int8_t;
   typedef signed short      int16_t;
   typedef signed int        int32_t;
   typedef unsigned char     uint8_t;
   typedef unsigned short    uint16_t;
   typedef unsigned int      uint32_t;
#else
   typedef signed __int8     int8_t;
   typedef signed __int16    int16_t;
   typedef signed __int32    int32_t;
   typedef unsigned __int8   uint8_t;
   typedef unsigned __int16  uint16_t;
   typedef unsigned __int32  uint32_t;
#endif
typedef signed __int64       int64_t;
typedef unsigned __int64     uint64_t;
```

Comment: No need to write typedef signed __ ?

Comment: after that if u use anywhere int64_t then compiler will understand signed __int64

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you you are trying to use MSVC specific `__int64` type with GCC. That does not work, use `long long` instead.

Comment: Actually I am building [this](http://code.google.com/p/idoubs/wiki/Building_iDoubs_v2_x) code.