# Error when compiling in cygwin -- error: unknown type name '_int64' -- (jni.h)

Tags: java-native-interface, cygwin

After I run the following command, then I receive an error

```
gcc prog.c -o prog -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/include" -I"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_25/include/win32"

error: unknown type name '_int64'
```

Please tell me how to fix this error.

### Code

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_mindtherobot_samples_ndkfoo_NdkFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```

Comment: What does `prog.c` look like? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7174654 -> `#include <inttypes.h>`. Also you are using the win32/ includes.

Comment: #include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

jstring Java_com_mindtherobot_samples_ndkfoo_NdkFooActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}

Answer (score 34):

the following should help alleviate this issue:

> ## [Building JNI-based Java Applications under Linux and Cygwin](http://www.graphics-muse.org/wp/?page_id=147#sthash.xPJXMaV7.dpuf)
>
> ### Java mods for Cygwin Builds
>
> Under Cygwin, the JNI (Java Native Interface) library we created called JNILibrary doesn’t build because gcc doesn’t know about the type “__int64″. You’ll know you hit the problem if you see something like this:
>
> Building JNILibrary class and header…. 
>   In file included from /cygdrive/c/j2sdk1.4.2_12/include/jni.h:27,
>   from JNICrunch-common.h:25,
>   from JNICrunchHWInfo.c:31:
>   /cygdrive/c/j2sdk1.4.2_12/include/win32/jni_md.h:16: error: parse error before “jlong”. 
>   /cygdrive/c/j2sdk1.4.2_12/include/win32/jni_md.h:16: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
>
> If you do hit this, then you need to edit /cygdrive/c/j2sdk1.4.2_12/include/win32/jni_md.h and change these lines:
>
> ```
> typedef long jint;
> typedef __int64 jlong;
> typedef signed char jbyte;
> ```
>
> to:
>
> ```
> typedef long jint;
> #ifdef __GNUC__
> typedef long long jlong;
> #else
> typedef __int64 jlong;
> #endif
> typedef signed char jbyte;
> ```

You could also try the following:

1. Add `#include <stdint.h>` before `#include <jni.h>` in the header... ***or***
2. Add the java compiler flag: `-D__int64=int64_t`

Comment: I can't save after i edited the jni_md.h file, how? please help.

Comment: if that didn't work, undo the changes you made and just try one of the other steps below.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, but in a test I only got the right sum after changing `typedef long jint;` to `typedef int jint;`.

Comment: jni_md.h file could not be editable in ide due to permissions issue. Can be tried outside from notepad or so with admin rights. Anyway it helped! Thanks