# JNI Demo HelloWorld

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

Here is my first `JNI` demo.My os is win7 and my ide is IDEA.

### Create Java File HelloWorld

HelloWold.java:

```
public class HelloWorld {
        public static native void sayHello();

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           new HelloWorld().sayHello();
        }

        static {
            System.load("D:\\JavaJNIDemo\\jni\\helloworld.dll");
        }

}
```

### Javah generates .h file

com_uniquestudio_coxier_HelloWorld.h:

```
#include <jni.h>
#ifndef _Included_com_uniquestudio_coxier_HelloWorld
#define _Included_com_uniquestudio_coxier_HelloWorld
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     com_uniquestudio_coxier_HelloWorld
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_uniquestudio_coxier_HelloWorld_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

### New a c file

HelloWorld.c:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "com_uniquestudio_coxier_HelloWorld.h"


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_uniquestudio_coxier_HelloWorld_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass object){
   printf("Hello World!\n");
   return;
  }
```

### generate dll on my win7

I met a problem :

> unknown type name "__int64" in `jni_md.h`

I solved it by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891478/error-when-compiling-in-cygwin)

Then I use :

```
D:\JavaJNIDemo\jni>gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_
HOME%\include\win32" -shared -o helloworld.dll HelloWorld.c
```

### Error

When I run the program,I get this error:
error:

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000180105979, pid=6776, tid=7040

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
C  [cygwin1.dll+0xc5979]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
D:\JavaJNIDemo\hs_err_pid6776.log
```

Comment: Looks like you compiled your c code with 32 bit gcc compiler and your are using 64 bit jvm.

Comment: Maybe you are right.I use MINGW  to compile .c file and I get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\JavaJNIDemo\jni\helloworld.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`  ) @SMA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change compiler to [MinGW64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/).Then it works