# Using a 64bit SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, 64-bit, canon-sdk

I'm sorry in advance if this question is not well expressed, I am trying to achieve something quite new to me and I am a little lost.

I am trying to include a Canon SDK inside an Objective-C wrapper, I understand from this paragraph that I needed to download the 64bit SDK:

> There are a few steps that need to be taken in order to use EOSFramework in a project. First, ensure that you have downloaded the latest Canon EDSDK 64bit. EOSFramework currently relies on ARC which is only supported in 64bit. Therefore you must use the 64bit version of EDSDK. Also ensure that you have compiled or downloaded the latest version of EOSFramework as a .framework file.

Incidentally, after following instructions, the errors that I'm getting while building the frameworks are related to 64bit. Please see picture attached:

[image: Errors]

Can someone point out a way for me to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this won't bring a problem in the long run, but I found an answer in this post: [_int64 does not name a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174583/int64-does-not-name-a-type)

Following this:

> It looks like you you are trying to use MSVC specific __int64 type with GCC. That does not work, use long long instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone point out a way for me to figure this out?

You need to track down the declaration of `EdsUInt64` *in the SDK you have downloaded* and figure out why it is not being seen by the compiler when compiling the source you've shown.

Try right-clicking on `EdsUInt32` (which the compiler was happy with) and jumping to its definition. Now look around, are the 64-bit types defined in the same place? Are they inside `#if` constructs? If so why are the conditions not true? Etc. Do some detective work.

You can also use TextWrangler/BBEdit, or other good editor, to do quick multi-file searches over all the SDK source to find the definitions.

If you don't find the definitions then you've got the wrong version of one of the SDKs, go back to Canon and get the right one.

The solution is very unlikely to be you needing to define the type yourself. The ARC comments in particular indicate you do have Mac specific source code, Canon compile it on a Mac, so it's unlikely to be a MS or Gnu specific issue failing on a Mac etc.

Good Hunting!

HTH